# Git ! [rejected]

Tags: git

I'm working on learning rails and I'm new to Git. I downloaded the zip file of my last commit from Git yesterday because I made a mess of my project and wanted to backtrack (now I'm sensing that was not the way to handle it). Any way - how do I merge my updated project with the original? This is what Git is telling me.

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:xxxxxx/xxxxx.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: Do a `git pull` before you `git push`.

Comment: do `git pull` to merge the updates.

Comment: @vee I did a git pull and this is what I got: There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details

Comment: You don't have upstream specified, you could either set it using `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master` before `git pull` or specify remote branch in git pull with `git pull origin master`.

Comment: Duplicate of [Issue pushing new code in Github](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939648/issue-pushing-new-code-in-github)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `git fetch` and then `git rebase`. In this case it won't pollute history with merges. If you have uncommitted changes you can save it aside with `git stash`. When you are done with fetch & rebase, you can return it back with `git stash pop`.

Comment: Instead of doing a rebase, the original poster could just `git merge` after the fetch too, though of course that may or may not result in a different commit history graph.

Answer (score 0):

The remote repository contains already some changes (probably made via the web ui or yesterday ? ) do a 'git pull' as proposed.
If you want to lose your local changes, you can delete your local repository and do 'git clone ...'