# How to disconnect project to github repo and connect to another?

Tags: git, git-push

I'm a little lost. I worked on a project, which is coupled with github. But I made the project evolve and therefore I created on github a new repository with which I wish to work (while keeping aside the old one with the old files).

So in my project I want to make sure that it is no longer coupled to the old repository and that I can work normally from the new one.

I followed some links and so I did:

- Creation of my new repository on Github
- In my project : `git remote rm origin`
- `git remote add origin [newGithubURL]`
- `git init` , `git add .` , `git commit -m "first commit"`
- `git push origin master`

But I've this error :

[image]

Comment: Do you want it to truly be a new repository as if it started from scratch, or do you want to retain your old commits for reference?

Comment: If you're not concerned about what's currently in the new repository, you could try `git push --force origin master`

Comment: I want it to be a new repository so that I balance all of my files in it. And concerning the previous deposit, I leave it aside with the old commits

Comment: @eronn if the solution @Mike Faber provided does not work, I have had success by copying the entire local folder to a new folder, deleting the `.git` folder in the new one, then doing `git init` etc. as you have described. That way it is treated as a new repository with no history.

Comment: Okay it works thank you very much! The problem was the readme! So I was able to put everything in the new repo. Good by cons he put me all my previous commit and I would have preferred to act as if I started from scratch but good

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue pushing new code in Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939648/issue-pushing-new-code-in-github)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-push%5D+updates+were+rejected

Comment: This might be similar issue and it shows a different approach.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181845/git-push-existing-repo-to-a-new-and-different-remote-repo-server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Mike Faber provided a great solution that would retain the history of the old repository within the new one.

If you want to start over from scratch as if it were a brand new repository, what I have done is:

1. Copy the local working folder for the old repository to a new folder
2. Rename the new folder to what you want it to be, or, archive or rename the old folder as a backup
3. Delete the `.git` folder in the new working folder
4. In the new folder, do `git init`, `git add .` , `git commit -m "first commit"` as you normally would to push to GitHub

Now you have a copy of the old repository, as a new repository, starting with only one commit.