# Issue while pushing first version of local code to bitbucket repo

Tags: c#, .net, git, visual-studio, bitbucket

I am trying to push first draft of my .Net code (written in Visual Studio) to bitbucket. Locally I am working on the master branch.

1. I created an empty repo in bitbucket.It is empty because i cannot see any read me or license file there
2. I added the remote url in Visual Studio through Team Explorer-> Settings
3. I did the code changes and can see the changes in TeamExplorer -> Changes. I am working on Master branch locally.
4. I committed the changes and then tried to push the code using the push link on sync window

I got an error saying that updates were rejected because

> remote contains work that you don't have locally

Also I can see this message in my sync window enter image description here

[image]

I then tried `git push -u origin master`. This gives a message `Everything up-to-datAt line:1 char:1`

This a different from [Issue pushing new code in Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939648/issue-pushing-new-code-in-github)  as i don't have any file on remote repository that i can see

Comment: I don't think you did step #2 correctly nor did you `pull <remote>`.  Anyway the easiest thing to do after #1 is to open Git Bash and perform a `git clone <URL-to-your-Bitbucket-repo>`.  That eliminates the need for #2 which can lead to a) getting it wrong b) having _orphaned_ code on _either end_ which sounds like is your case

Comment: Please follow this tutorial.  https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/learn-git-with-bitbucket-cloud.   Do everything up to and including Step 1.  After that you can use VS.  This is the best way whenever starting a new repo.  After that you can use VS as normal