# "Updates were rejected" trying to push to Github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I know there are similar questions to this, but nothing that has been suggested is working for me, and I'm losing my mind with this!

Quick rundown: Completely new to programming. Started from scratch on learning Rails with a book.

I'm on a mac(osx 10.7.5),I've installed Ruby, Rails, and Git (and the needed command line tools), but git/github is definitely giving me problems.
I followed what was suggested here: [Github "Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328800/github-updates-were-rejected-because-the-remote-contains-work-that-you-do-not-h)

So first I did:

```
git remote add origin https:/github.com/MY_USER/learn-rails.git
```

and I get:

```
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

I then move on to:

```
git push -u origin master
```

and I keep getting the following error:

```
![rejected]master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/MY_USER_NAME/learn-rails.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

I go ahead and try:

```
git pull origin master
```

which gives me this:

```
From https://github.com/MY_USER/learn-rails
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Auto-merging config/initializers/secret_token.rb
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in config/initializers/secret_token.rb
Auto-merging config/environments/development.rb
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in config/environments/development.rb
Auto-merging Gemfile.lock
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in Gemfile.lock
Auto-merging Gemfile
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in Gemfile
Auto-merging .gitignore
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in .gitignore
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Even more background info: This is my second go around with this test/learning project due to having completely different problems pushing to Github previously. I scratched the whole thing and started fresh from chapter one, hoping that I might of just missed something when I was setting up GIt. I was previously have a ver stubborn problem with Github telling me the repository doesn't exist. I tried so many things to try and fix that problem, that I lost track of what I had even tried. So I just wanted to start clean. I deleted the "Learn-Rails" directory on my computer, and recreated it for this go around. I deleted the previous repository from my Github account, and now have started a new one, but it was named the same exact thing before. Would that cause an issue?

Comment: Firstly do a `git commit -m "message"` or `git commit -A "message"`

Comment: `git push origin master -f`

Comment: Thank you @scaryguy I did do that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, check what the origin is. Open `.git/config` from your app root. should have something like this in there:

```
[remote "origin"]
  url = git@github.com:tomdunning/gideons.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

The next issue you had was the pull brought in a merge conflict. Run `git mergetool` to start managing the merge for each issue until all are resolved.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  I do that in my file, along with this above it: [core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = true
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true
 ignorecase = true
 precomposeunicode = false

Comment: When I run mergetool, I'm told that it isn't configured, and then I get this: 'git mergetool' will now attempt to use one of the following tools:
opendiff kdiff3 tkdiff xxdiff meld tortoisemerge gvimdiff diffuse ecmerge p4merge araxis bc3 codecompare emerge vimdiff
Merging:
.gitignore
Gemfile
Gemfile.lock
config/environments/development.rb
config/initializers/secret_token.rb

Comment: When I run mergetool help, I get:'git mergetool --tool-<tool>' may be set to one of the following:
  emerge
  opendiff
  vimdiff
  vimdiff2

The following tools are valid, but not currently available:
  araxis
  bc3
  codecompare
  deltawalker
  diffmerge
  diffuse
  ecmerge
  gvimdiff
  gvimdiff2
  kdiff3
  meld
  p4merge
  tkdiff
  tortoisemerge
  xxdiff

Comment: Thank you. I did have to go ahead and install a mergetool. I picked Diffmerge, and then I found what the issues were.