# Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm trying to move a local repository to bitbucket, I'm following this [tutorial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/importing-code-from-an-existing-project-776640909.html) but when I do

```
git push --all bitbucket
```

I got the following meessage error:

```
To https://bitbucket.org/growtec/offshore.git
 ! [rejected]        Leonardo -> Leonardo (fetch first)
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://lrslima@bitbucket.org/growtec/offshore.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I'm on master branch and I already did a `git pull` but the output was the Everything up-to-date.

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328800/github-updates-were-rejected-because-the-remote-contains-work-that-you-do-not-h) but it didn't work for me

Comment: I recommend *avoiding* `git pull` entirely, but since you are using it: (1) what remotes do you have (`git remote` will list them)? (2) what is the `upstream` setting of your `master` branch name? (`git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{upstream}` will show it.) (3) what is the `upstream` setting of your `Leonardo` branch name?

Answer (score 3):

You did a `git pull` on the `master` branch, but if you look closely at what your `git push --all bitbucket` command is doing, it's also trying to push the `Leonardo` branch, which you never pulled.  You can try pulling this branch as well, and then push all again:

```
git checkout Leonardo
git pull origin Leonardo
git push --all bitbucket
```

Comment: I tried this but i'm still getting the same message error

Comment: Did you pull `master` again, as new commits to the remote `master` may have happened since you last pulled?

Comment: Yes, everything is up-to-date.

Answer (score 3):

If everything is already up to date. Try `git push -f origin master.` -f stands for force commit. Hope this helps.

Comment: It is dangerous to force push ... It is better to solve the issue with other ways

Answer (score 2):

You need to pull (or fetch and merge) the 2 branches master and Leonardo solve all the conflicts commit then push again

Answer (score 1):

just this code using terminal :

git push -f origin master

Comment: > It is dangerous to force push ... It is better to solve the issue with other ways.

Answer (score 0):

```
git pull origin master
git fetch origin Leonardo:Leonardo
git push --all bitbucket
```

Comment: Could you please explain how your suggestion solves the original problem.  Code only answers should generally be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue
[Github "Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328800/github-updates-were-rejected-because-the-remote-contains-work-that-you-do-not-h)

```
git remote add origin [//your github url]

//pull those changes

git pull origin master 

// or optionally, 'git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories' if you have 
initialized repo in github and also committed locally

//now, push your work to your new repo

git push origin master
```