# Unable to push to git repository

Tags: git

I am trying to push my project but getting rejected as errors and I am not able to understand the errors.

```
$ git push origin master
To https://github.com/sunil887/Angular2App.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/sunil887/Angular2App.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: Your local head is not in the last version. Do `git pull origin master`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Github "Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328800/github-updates-were-rejected-because-the-remote-contains-work-that-you-do-not-h)

Comment: Don't post images of code or text. Post the code or the text as is.

Comment: What's the _exact_ error message? It's important to read those; they are usually designed to be helpful in finding and solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do `git pull` before you try to push. This should either fix the issue or give you more information about what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you need to

```
git pull
```

first.

Your remote has changes that don't exist on your local machine.

if this

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step-by-step procedure that you will need to do with consideration of a possible `merge conflict`.

1. Do `git pull` to update your local repository.
2. There might be a `merge conflict` after doing `git pull` and you will see this in your terminal. If this happens, check which files cause the conflict with `git status`.
3. After fixing the `merge conflicts` (if any), you can now proceed with adding and committing your local changes with `git add -A` and `git commit -m [commit message]`
4. Finally, do a `git push [upstream] [branch]`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your remote git. Your changes might already be there.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue:

[image: Image of command prompt]

And, to get rid of the error:

you should not use `git push origin master`. But, you should use `git push origin main`.

Comment: main is just an alternate name to the master and there exists no real difference between master and main