# How to fix this error popping up on git while I am trying to push the project to a repo?

Tags: git, github

I am getting this error whenever I try to push my project to github:

> error: failed to push some refs to
>   'https://github.com/projectlink.git' hint: Updates were rejected
>   because the remote contains work that you do not have locally. This is
>   usually caused by another repository pushing to the same ref. You may
>   want to first integrate the remote changes (e.g., 'git pull ...')
>   before pushing again. See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push
>   --help' for details.

I also tried to pull it and then push the code but I still get the same error. Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid repetitive message \`Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do...\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49175460/how-to-avoid-repetitive-message-updates-were-rejected-because-the-remote-contai)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git: updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357108/git-updates-were-rejected-because-the-remote-contains-work-that-you-do-not-have)

Comment: If you've pulled and then pushed and still get the same error them you've pulled a wrong branch, not the one you pushed. Please show you branches and commands that led to the error.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen when

- Your branch was updated by another dev, so you first have to pull and merge your working copy, then push another commit
- You have rebased your branch, in this case all commits are re-written so you have to force-push your branch
- You have amended your commit that was pushed before. Also in this case the history has changed and you have to force-push.

Anyway with the info you gave use it is very hard to help you, we need some context.