# error: src refspec main does not match any error: failed to push some refs to <url>

Tags: git, github

1. To get practice with Github, I created a new directory on my computer that I wanted to push to Github.
2. I added a .csv file and nothing else.
3. I created a new repo on Github without initializing a README.
4. I cd'd into the directory then used the following commands in Terminal:

`git init`

`git add file1.csv`

`git commit -m "First commit"`

`git remote add origin <Github url from Quick Setup page>`

`git push -u origin main`

And I got the following errors:

`error: src refspec main does not match any`

`error: failed to push some refs to <url>`

I searched for a solution and I came across this: [git error: failed to push some refs to remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114676/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to-remote)
The answer selected says:

> If the GitHub repo has seen new commits pushed to it, while you were
> working locally, I would advise using:

> `git pull --rebase origin master`

> `git push origin master`

What I don't understand is, why did this happen with a **new** directory on my computer and a **new** repo? No commits were made to the repo on Github so why should I have to `git pull`? I even tried doing this with a new empty directory and new empty repo (again) and I got the same result.

Comment: This could happen because of a typo. Technically the error means the repo is empty or no commit is made.

Comment: Your new repository with one new commit created one new branch name. Why do you believe that this new branch name is `main`? The default new branch name is actually `master`. You must take some particular action to change this. (A future Git release might have a different initial default name, but for now, it remains `master`.)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is an unpleasant result of the `master` vs `main` controversy.

Your local GIT client created a default branch called `master` (when you initialized the repo with `git init`), but the remote repository on GitHub has no `master` - instead the default branch is called `main`.

---

**Solution A** - if you want to name the branch `master`

Run `git push -u origin master` **instead of** `git push -u origin main`

Or **Solution B** - if you want to name the branch `main`

Run `git checkout -B main` **before** `git push -u origin main`

Comment: That's exactly what it was. I repeated the process all over again but this time I used `git push -u origin master` and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @IamWarmduscher Ugh, do you have to do this every time??

Comment: @KalebCoberly You don't. Just this one time when you're connecting your local repo to the origin.

Comment: @IamWarmduscher, haha, thanks. That's what I meant. I guess it's too late now for GitHub to git with Git on this and save us all the trouble.

Comment: When I run `git checkout -B main` and then `git push -u origin main` I get the `error: failed to push some refs` and `Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally`

Comment: @BrianWiley That's why you need to run it "**before**" (see my answer last line), not "**then**". Please doublecheck the question (with the original ordering) and the answer.

Comment: I'm confused I ran `git checkout -B main` before `git push -u origin main`

Comment: @BrianWiley In that case it's possible your remote branch is ahead of your local, which is a different issue. If it's the case, it's better explained in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18328842/1693192

Answer (score 3):

I solved that problem using

```
git branch -M master main
```

There, you only rename the branch. That solved the problem you wrote

I learn about it with Git official documentation
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch

Answer (score 2):

**Hello every one,**
first change to main branch :

```
git checkout main
```

After git merge to master :

```
git merge master
```

And final git push :

```
git push
```