# In updated GitHub version where it asks for authentication key instead of password

Tags: git, github

In updated GitHub version where it asks for authentication key instead of password it's showing an error

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Kalim22/Small-projects.git';
```

[image]

Comment: Someone else has commited to the repository, rebase or merge your changes onto remote changes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github "Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328800/github-updates-were-rejected-because-the-remote-contains-work-that-you-do-not-h)

Answer (score 0):

- You made a new, empty repository on GitHub, then told *GitHub* to put *one commit* into this repository.  That one commit had some files in it: probably a README and/or LICENSE and the like.  This is GitHub's preferred method of creating a repository, because creating a repository **and putting one commit into it** avoids certain problems (while creating others!).  This created a branch named `main`.
- You then made a new, empty repository on your laptop.  You then put *one commit* into this repository, which created a branch named `master`.

You asked your Git to send your branch `main` to GitHub, but you did not have a branch named `main`: you had one named `master` instead, with your one commit on it.  So you renamed `master` to `main`.

You retried the `git push` and got an error telling you that your push would, if they (GitHub) accepted it, cause them to *lose* their one initial commit entirely.  The question you must answer for yourself now is: *Is there any value to you to* keep *that one commit that you had GitHub create for you?*

If there *is* some value, you'll need to combine *your* initial commit with *their* initial commit.  There are existing questions here on StackOverflow for this (see the how-to-ask document again).  If there is *no* value to the GitHub initial commit, consider simply overwriting it, using `git push -u --force origin main`.