# I am new to git and github and facing this issue while pushing some changes into GitHub repo

Tags: git, github

```
! [rejected]        main -> main (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/jayasimhag1reddy/timpass.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not
hint: have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing to
hint: the same ref. If you want to integrate the remote changes, use
hint: 'git pull' before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: And did you `git pull` like it specifically suggested?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github "Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328800/github-updates-were-rejected-because-the-remote-contains-work-that-you-do-not-h)

Comment: Make an effort.

Answer (score 2):

you need to understand the basic concept of GIT, which is you should not push changes to a remote repository if you are out of sync.

Of course, you can do it with the `force` - `git push -f` but the results will be that the work that you did not have locally will be deleted from the server since you "forced" the server to accept your changes without "getting" ant changes made by others.

#### Why do you need to pull?

[image]

- In this example, you created a branch from `C2`.
- while you still writing your code someone else had `committed` and `pushed` (uploaded) to the server commits `C3` and `C4` which you **don't have locally**
- If you will push your code you will **overwrite* the server and you will *delete* those commits
- In order to **sync** your local copy (branch) of the code with the server you need to run `git pull` which actually executes `git fetch && git merge` for you.

---

A very detailed explanation can be found here:
https://git-scm.com/book/id/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches

Comment: nice explaination!

Answer (score 1):

The response from git is telling you the answer: "hint: 'git pull' before pushing again".

You need to do a

```
$ git pull
```

or a

```
$ git fetch
$ git merge
```

To get the changes on the git server (github in this case).

Answer (score 0):

The repository has different commits on different local devices.
You can merge commits or go back to a previous commit where the commits started to differ.