# Add project as a branch to an existing project in git

Tags: git

I have an existing project in git that other users have access to and has many branches: `example_project_a`.

On my machine, i have a variation of that project with lots of changes on my machine and it is not in git yet.

How can I add my current project as a branch of `example_project_a` so that I share my changes with the group?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897723/how-to-add-my-current-project-to-an-already-existing-github-repository) similar question pushes it to the master of the existing but i don't want to affect master.

Comment: You should be able to follow the same steps as in the linked answer, except use `git push -u origin <remote-branch-name>` to push to a different remote branch instead of `master`.

Answer (score 7):

Based on the comment from 0x5453 and [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27223242/11312528) worked:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "my commit"
git remote add origin <remote repository URL>
git push origin <remote branch name>
```